# How to Switch off and ON the toggle Button based on the click event on icon

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, toggle

In my angular application I have some font icons and also I have one toggle switch ,by default the toggle switch is in ON state.

And My requirement is when I click on any of the icon(the color of the icon should changed from white to red and this was done).the toggle switch should turned to OFF state and when we click on the toggle switch the colored icon should changed to white from red.

**.component.html**

```
<label class="rating-switch" id="toggleSwitch">
      <input class="rating-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked >
      <div class="slide round"  >

      </div>
    </label>    <span class="no-rating-switch" >No Rating</span>

<div class="container">
<span class="iconss"></span><i (click)="selectedIcon = icon.id" class="stl" [ngClass]="icon.class"
  [style.color]="selectedIcon === icon.id ? '#FF0000' : '#ffffff'" *ngFor="let icon of icons"></i>
</div>
```

**.component.css**

```
icons = [
    { id: 1, class: "icon-1" },
    { id: 2, class: "icon-2" },
    { id: 3, class: "icon-3" },
    { id: 4, class: "icon-4" },
    { id: 5, class: "icon-5" },
    { id: 6, class: "icon-6" },
    { id: 7, class: "icon-7" },
   
];
```

So as mentioned above I have to switch off the toggle button (means unchecked)when I click on the icon and when I click on the switch the colored icon should changed to white.

I have tried with multiple ways can anyone help me on this.

Comment: In the Angular docs https://angular.io/guide/event-binding. - `(click)` calls a method. Try using a method, with the assignment inside it. Also square brackets in CSS? I have never seen them used other than something like `input[type="radio"]`

Comment: It's my mistake it is Typescript file (.ts)

Comment: thanks @JGFMK ,I have tried with ngModel but not working as expected, Could you please edit the above code.Then it would be more helpful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a bad idea to toggle multiple icons with one switch (and be able to toggle them manually on a click), it confuses me. But nevermind, here you go.

First you need to declare a state of each of your icons, so you know which one is active/inactive (if there is any logic behind this, you want to know).

Every time you click on an icon which state changes to active, it becomes red. When you click on the toggle, and its state changes to inactive, all of your icons will change back to white.

component.html:

```
 <label class="rating-switch" id="toggleSwitch">
    <input class="rating-checkbox" type="checkbox" [checked]="toggleState" (change)="onToggleClicked($event)">
    <div class="slide round">

    </div>
  </label> <span class="no-rating-switch">No Rating</span>

  <div class="container">
    <span class="iconss"></span>
    <i (click)="onIconClick(icon)" class="stl" [class]="icon- + i"
       [style.color]="icon.active === true ? '#FF0000' : '#ffffff'" *ngFor="let icon of icons; let i = index">
    </i>
  </div>
```

component.ts:

```
  toggleState = true;
  icons = [
    {id: 1, class: 'icon-1', active: false},
    {id: 2, class: 'icon-2', active: false},
    {id: 3, class: 'icon-3', active: false},
    {id: 4, class: 'icon-4', active: false},
    {id: 5, class: 'icon-5', active: false},
    {id: 6, class: 'icon-6', active: false},
    {id: 7, class: 'icon-7', active: false},
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  onIconClick(icon: any) {
    let iconToEdit = this.icons.find(ico => ico.id === icon.id);
    if (iconToEdit && !iconToEdit.active) {
      this.icons.forEach(i => i.active = false);
      iconToEdit.active = !iconToEdit.active;
      this.markToggleAsActive();
    } else {
      this.icons.forEach(i => i.active = false);
    }
  }

  onToggleClicked(event: any) {
    this.toggleState = event.target.checked;
    this.markIconsAsInactive();
  }

  markIconsAsInactive() {
    if (!this.toggleState) {
      this.icons.forEach(icon => icon.active = false);
    }
  }

  markToggleAsActive() {
    this.toggleState = !!this.icons.find(icon => icon.active);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sickpig, but In the above code when we click on icon the color should changed to red and when we click on another icon the first icon color should changed to white which means at a time only one icon color has to change not multiple icons can you help me on this.

Comment: @user1 - that is easy to remedy - in the onclick, repeat the code inside the if of markIconsAsInactive() method above first.

Comment: @JGFMK correct :) i have updated my code example

Comment: Thanks @sickpig, it is absolutely working for me and one more small thing is in the above html code <span class="iconss"></span> I have mentioned the numbers below the icon by using increment in css I have implemented but I need to add those numbers based on the number of icons (used the css styles for iconss class for writing the numbers and incrementing ,but I need to add dynamically based on the number of icons. Could you help on this

Comment: I updated the for loop to have another value (index) and the class attribute. Now your first icon has to be 0 in your css increment function to be equal with the index. In additon, there is no need for your class object on your item array anymore.